# How to get openxml of cells and objects (like charts,shapes and pictures) in excel VSTO?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins, vba

The way we can extract openxml for shapes and pictures from Word document using VSTO, i want to do the same for excel. I tried looping through the custom xml parts but no luck.

```
Excel.Workbook doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
        foreach (Microsoft.Office.Core.CustomXMLPart p in doc.CustomXMLParts)
        {
            string bn = p.DocumentElement.BaseName;
            string cxml = p.XML;
        }
```

Code for Word works like this. ctrl is a bookmark and GetInnerRange returns the range of that bookmark.

```
Word.Range inner = GetInnerRange(ctrl);
            string xml = inner.WordOpenXML;
```